# Removing duplicate entries from a DataTable that exist in another DataTable?

Tags: c#

You'd think that it would be simple, isn't there something simple to do this? All I want to do is to remove some duplicate rows. I can obviously save off the PK into a separate list and iterate through that to delete the rows, and may be what I end up doing. It just seems like I'm missing some obvious solution here.

```
        foreach (var v in FinalData.Visitors)
        {
            bool isDup = (AlreadyCommittedData.Visitors.Any(vdup => vdup.vid == v.vid));
            if (isDup)
            {
                v.Delete();
            }
        }
```

### Fails with 'foreach collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute'

Two minutes later after googling... My second try was something like...

```
        var vDup = new LMDB.VisitorsDataTable();

        foreach (var v in FinalData.Visitors)
        {
            bool isDup = (AlreadyCommittedData.Visitors.Any(vdup => vdup.vid == v.vid));
            if (isDup)
            {
                vDup.AddVisitorRow(v);
            }
        }
        foreach (var v in vDup)
        {
            FinalData.Visitors.Remove(v);
        }
```

### Gave me an error something like...Row exists in another table

My third try is simple brute force ;) Since the duplicates are all at the front, it actually may perform pretty well.

//Still being tested, there may be a typo, if so, please ignore it.
            bool allDone;

```
        do
        {
            allDone = true;
            foreach (var v in FinalData.Visitors)
            {
                bool isDup = (AlreadyCommittedData.Visitors.Any(vdup => vdup.vid == v.vid));
                if (isDup)
                {
                    v.Delete();
                    allDone = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        while (!allDone);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track with your second option. However, the row may never be in more than one table at the same time. Declare vdup to be a List`<LMDB.VisitorsDataRow`>.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two data tables (dtA and dtB), you want to get all the records in A that are not already in B.  To do this, merge table A into table B like so:

```
dtB.Merge(dtA);
dtA = dtB.GetChanges(); // this will give you records unique to table A
// optional:
dtB.RejectChanges(); // restore dtB to its original state
```